# MVC .NET Prompt a user for logon

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I'm at a loss. Right now my site will redirect to a logon page if the user's session has timed out. One problem I want to solve is when the user clicks an action button while logged in they create an ajax request.
I want to catch the timeout before the ajax call is run, popup a modal dialog box prompting the user for their username and password then making the ajax call after the successful logon. 
My main goal is to make the ajax call run after the successful logon I don't necessarily need to make a popup but I figured that would be the best way.
What I have done so far is this. I have created a controller who's purpose in life is to tell me if there is a timeout. In the ajaxStart() function I load a div with results of calling that controller. If the html in that div contains the words 'Log On' then I call window.showModalDialog. This sometimes works and some times it doesn't. To me this feels like a hack and there has to be a better way of getting it done. Any ideas??

```
function ajaxStart() {
        var timeoutTest = $('#timeoutTest');
        timeoutTest.load(timeoutUrl);
        if (timeoutTest.html().indexOf('Log On') != -1) {
            window.showModalDialog(logonUrl, "", "dialogHeight: 600; dialogWidth: 400");
        }

        tid = setTimeout(showSpinner, 500);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you taking a look at the [following article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx) in which Phil Haack illustrates a technique that would allow you to configure your application to send 401 status code if the authentication ticket has expired and the request was made using AJAX. Then you could very easily catch this 401 status code on the client and show the modal dialog. You could even do this globally for all AJAX requests occurring on the page by subscribing to the [`.ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) event handler and handle those errors in a single place.

Comment: I do something similar to that to redirect to the logon page. My goal in this isn't to redirect to the logon page. My goal is to get the user to re-logon before the ajax request is sent then once they have logged on the ajax request will continue. So the flow would be as follows. 1. User Click on action. 2. Timeout is detected. 3. User is prompted to logon. 4. User logs on. 5. Action executes.

Comment: @YetAnotherSoftwareDeveloper, you cannot know if the authentication ticket is expired without actually sending a request. So the flow should be: 1. you send a request to the action 2. you detect the 401 status code on the client 3. you show a modal logon form allowing the user to input his credentials 4. upon successful login you redirect him to the page that he was initially requesting

Comment: My approach would allow you to re-fire your event. You'd just have to pass in the "oustanding" function/data in to the method that handles the login popup when a requires_auth is returned.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, I have a controller that is called in the code above at the timeoutUrl. That is sent to a controller that will return a blank page if there's no timeout. If there is a time out that call will return the login page. That's how a detect the timeout in step 2. I do this in the ajaxStart() function because this happens before the ajax request is sent. This does work for me the user is able to log in and afterwards the request does continue but it doesn't work 100% of the time... it works maybe 40% of the time.

Comment: @YetAnotherSoftwareDeveloper, that's why I suggested you to modify your server logic to return 401 HTTP status code instead of redirecting to a login page.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov I could do that but then how would I rerun the ajax request without the user needing to click the action again?

Comment: You could AJAXify the process of submitting the form that contains the login credentials and in the success callback rerun your initial AJAX request which will succeed this time because the authentication cookie will be renewed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with using ajax error is redirecting to the logon page really isn't an ajax error and you may need to use that for other things. Your login page probablys shouldn't always return a 401 IMHO either as it is actually a public page.

I make sure my login page returns a custom header attribute that I can look for. We use a lot of ajax and you can have a script globally that looks for it (which will prevent the page from being displayed and allow you to do what you like.

Your login page controller method would look like:

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
{

    Response.AddHeader("REQUIRES_AUTH", "1");
    return View();
}
```

Then globally, you can have this jquery to deal with it...

```
$(document).bind("ajaxComplete", function (event, request, settings) {
    if (request.getResponseHeader("REQUIRES_AUTH") == "1") {
        ... addd popup code here.
    };
});
```

PS the reason yours doesn't always work is your timeout test would have to catch the expiry before the user posts. That's a bit of a lottery really and letting ajax complete is often the best. (remember, a login page is still a valid response to an ajax post, just not the one we want)

Comment: Interesting... that's a good idea to catch the timeout. How would I reRun that ajax call after the user logs back in though? The ajax request is done already.

Comment: Pubsub is worth looking at to subscribe, fire events. You could hook into that and fire once, then if it fails fire again after login logic (as long as the login response was also ajax) I like .net security and redirecting and prefer to leave it in place as other solutions create other problems later. Admittedly it's a more complex javascript solution, but I think a 401 is a bit hacky and could even lead to an authentication loop if you have different levels of access across your site.

Comment: +1 for explaining why the original approach of the poster didn't always work.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add an HTML class to `#timeoutTest`? Then you can do

```
timeoutTest.hasClass('logon');
```